# how to change collection config "delete source label" in TFS 2015 build definition

Tags: tfs-2015

I have a Build definition that creates a label on successful build.
I want to be able to delete the build, but retain the label.

1. When I delete the build manually, the label is deleted.
2. Also when selecting the option "retain indefinitely", the label is deleted when i delete the build manually
3. I am not able to change the value of "delete source label" in collection level (as there is no checkbox to change). See below.

[image]

How can i retain labels and be able to delete builds?

Answer (score 1):

I could reproduce your scenario. Even uncheck the "delete source label" option in Default Retention Policy. When manually delete "retain indefinitely" builds, the label is still deleted.

You can consider submitting a UserVoice at website below:

https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-2015

Comment: how did you change de Defaut Retention Policy ? I could change only in the build task .. the other one below, is only a label not editable.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding. I changed the Retention Policy as you did, in the build task. The settings in "Edit build Retention Policy" can't be modified.

Answer (score 0):

When you delete a vNext build manually, all the information will be deleted as the dialog indicated even though you have disabled "Delete source label" option.
[image]

There isn't any way to change this for now. You can submit a feature request for this as Cece's suggestion.

However, if you do want this feature for now, try with XMAL build system which allow you to choose what to keep when delete a build:
[image]